# Can I safely use int in Decimal calculations in Python?

Tags: python, decimal

I have used "decimal" constants, just in case. Could I rather use integers for the same purpose safely, like integer 0 and 1 here? Its for storing money.

```
    if SOMETHING:
        invoice.tax_rate = Decimal(TAXRATE_STRING)
    else:
        invoice.tax_rate = Decimal("0.00")
    invoice.total_amount =\
        invoice.pretax_amount * (Decimal("1") + invoice.tax_rate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can safely use integers; they'll be coerced to `Decimal` objects as required.

The `Decimal` class implements many of the [numeric emulation hooks](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) to do so, including the `__r*__` variants to ensure that this works even if the integer is the left-hand operand.

For your specific case, if the tax rate was set to integer `0` and you used an integer `1`, you'd get:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('20.00') * (1 + 0)
Decimal('20.00')
```

The summing of the tax rate results in a `Decimal` object if it is not set to integer `0`:

```
>>> 1 + Decimal('0.20')
Decimal('1.20')
```

etc.

Internally, the [`decimal._convert_other()` function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/67224c88144e/Lib/decimal.py#l5836) is used to handle the coercion. It'll convert integers and long integers to `Decimal()` always, floats only when explicitly instructed to (only for rich comparisons, so `==` and `<=`, etc.), the rest is explicitly rejected. Floats are not suited for automatic conversion; it is too easy to introduce bugs in your code if you allowed for floats to be converted implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, for example:

```
In [8]: d = decimal.Decimal("123.45")

In [9]: d / 10
Out[9]: Decimal('12.345')
```

Note that this does not work with floating-point values:

```
In [10]: d / 123.45
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

I would argue that this is good news, because implicitly mixing `Decimal` and `float` would be too error-prone.